# Do While Loop in Javascript

Tags: javascript, loops, do-while

I have a problem in my loop. I want to keep asking the user which ticket type to purchase and how many they would like to buy until `MAX_SEAT_COUNT <= totTickets`. My code would only run through the questions once. `MAX_SEAT_COUNT = 2200`

```
        do {
            ticketType = prompt ("Ticket Types: Toddlers = 1  Juniors = 2  Adults = 3 Please enter a ticket type: 1, 2, 3", "");
            if (ticketType == 1) {
                manyToddlers = prompt ("How many toddler tickets are you purchasing? You can only buy 10 tickets per ticket type.", "");
            } else if (ticketType == 2) {
                manyJuniors = prompt ("How many junior tickets are you purchasing? You can only buy 10 tickets per ticket type.", "");                  
            } else if (ticketType == 3) {
                manyAdults = prompt ("How many adult tickets are you purchasing? You can only buy 10 tickets per ticket type.", "");        
            } else {
                alert ("Please enter the correct number for each ticket type.");
            }

                if (manyToddlers <= 10) {
                    toddlersCounter = toddlersCounter + manyToddlers;
                    costToddlers = manyToddlers * toddlers;
                    alert ("You bought " + manyToddlers + " toddler tickets for $ " + costToddlers.toFixed(2)); 
                } else if (manyJuniors <= 10) {
                    juniorsCounter = juniorsCounter + manyJuniors;
                    costJuniors = manyJuniors * juniors;
                    alert ("You bought " + manyJuniors + " junior tickets for $ " + costJuniors.toFixed(2));    
                } else if (manyAdults <= 10) {
                    adultsCounter = adultsCounter + manyAdults;
                    costAdults = manyAdults * adults;
                    alert ("You bought " + manyAdults + " adult tickets for $ " + costAdults.toFixed(2));   
                } else {
                    alert ("You can only buy 10 tickets per ticket type.");
                }

        totTickets = toddlersCounter + juniorsCounter + adultsCounter;
        totSales = costToddlers + costJuniors + costAdults;     

        } while (MAX_SEAT_COUNT <= totTickets);
```

Comment: The prompt command always returns a string value so you should convert these text numbers to proper numerals by manyToddlers = parseInt( manyToddlers,10). The maths may also work as expected.

Comment: Don't you have the condition backwards? You should loop while the number of tickets is less than the maximum, not while it's greater.

Comment: looping to 2200 with max 10 steps per run and 3 alerts is really not recommended :) this would be 660 alerts to do... :S

Answer (score 1):

Your `while` condition is wrong. It should be:

```
while (totTickets <= MAX_SEAT_COUNT)
```

The loop is only running once because your condition is failing after the first loop.

Comment: Okay, I changed it and it's still asking the question one time.

Comment: Actually it doesn't matter if he uses `while` or `do-while`. The only difference is, the `do-while` goes through the process at least once and while firt checks conditions. And atm i can't see where he stores the data so the loop will allways start from beginning. That's the reason why it doesn't matters :)

Comment: @Dwza I didn't say anything about whether it should be `while` or `do-while`. My change is that it should be `totTickets <= MAX_SEAT_COUNT`, not `MAX_SEAT_COUNT <= totTickets`

Comment: hmm, i could swear i read some about use while not do while ^^ may i am working to long and read to much that my brain is faking me ^^

Answer (score 1):

I changed your code a bit, to get it easier to read, and make it work as well.
Your problem was in the structure of your `while` :

- Handle the user input if it's not 1, 2, or 3
- Get the right tickets count at the end
- Correctly loop while `totTickets <= MAX...`

Here is a sample of the structure if you want to have a look :

```
if (manyAdults <= 10) {
   adultsCounter = adultsCounter + manyAdults;
   costAdults = manyAdults * adults;
   alert("You bought " + manyAdults + " adult tickets for $ " + costAdults.toFixed(2));
} else {
   alert("You can only buy 10 tickets per ticket type.");
}

totTickets = totTickets + toddlersCounter + juniorsCounter + adultsCounter;
//don't forget to reset their values, otherwise your ticket count will grow instantly               
toddlersCounter = 0; juniorsCounter = 0; adultsCounter = 0;
totSales = costToddlers + costJuniors + costAdults;
```

I put a button in the Fiddle to control the launch of your while :)

Take a look at this **[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Laeqnfdv/)** with the entire code !

Answer (score 1):

there seem to be multiple problems :

1. Define all your variables and set them to a default value of 0 (or what suits you) before using them. For example if I choose adult type(3) in the first prompt, then variables manyToddlers and manyJuniors will remain undefined and now the second if(){} will throw an error of undefined in the operations.
2. make sure you parseInt from the prompt response.
3. change your while condition to totTickets <= MAX_SEAT_COUNT;

only as an example the code below should work fine , however i recommend you do it in a better way keeping all things clear and defined:

```
manyToddlers = 0;
    manyJuniors = 0;
    manyAdults = 0;

    toddlersCounter = 0;
    toddlers = 0;
    costToddlers = 0;

    juniorsCounter = 0;
    manyJuniors = 0;
    juniors =0;
    costJuniors = 0;

    adultsCounter = 0;
    costAdults = 0;
    adults = 0;

    totTickets = 0;
    MAX_SEAT_COUNT = 10;
    do {
        ticketType = prompt ("Ticket Types: Toddlers = 1  Juniors = 2  Adults = 3 Please enter a ticket type: 1, 2, 3", "");
        if (ticketType == 1) {
            manyToddlers = prompt ("How many toddler tickets are you purchasing? You can only buy 10 tickets per ticket type.", "");
        } else if (ticketType == 2) {
            manyJuniors = prompt ("How many junior tickets are you purchasing? You can only buy 10 tickets per ticket type.", "");
        } else if (ticketType == 3) {
            manyAdults = prompt ("How many adult tickets are you purchasing? You can only buy 10 tickets per ticket type.", "");
        } else {
            alert ("Please enter the correct number for each ticket type.");
        }

        manyToddlers = parseInt(manyToddlers,10);
        manyJuniors = parseInt(manyJuniors,10);
        manyAdults = parseInt(manyAdults,10);

        if (manyToddlers <= 10) {
            toddlersCounter = toddlersCounter + manyToddlers;
            costToddlers = manyToddlers * toddlers;
            alert ("You bought " + manyToddlers + " toddler tickets for $ " + costToddlers.toFixed(2));
        } else if (manyJuniors <= 10) {
            juniorsCounter = juniorsCounter + manyJuniors;
            costJuniors = manyJuniors * juniors;
            alert ("You bought " + manyJuniors + " junior tickets for $ " + costJuniors.toFixed(2));
        } else if (manyAdults <= 10) {
            adultsCounter = adultsCounter + manyAdults;
            costAdults = manyAdults * adults;
            alert ("You bought " + manyAdults + " adult tickets for $ " + costAdults.toFixed(2));
        } else {
            alert ("You can only buy 10 tickets per ticket type.");
        }

        totTickets = toddlersCounter + juniorsCounter + adultsCounter;
        totSales = costToddlers + costJuniors + costAdults;

    } while (totTickets <= MAX_SEAT_COUNT);
```

Comment: You won't get to 2200 if you keep this `totTickets = toddlersCounter + juniorsCounter + adultsCounter;`, and if you don't reset those vars except `totTickets` you will reach it in a few loops.

Comment: @user3241019 : I acknowledge and agree with what you say. This was supposed to be a help with the do while looping and so I set the MAX_TICKETS to ten. As for the actual program, a lot of improvements are required. For a start variables in loop are not required to be global and of course this is not a good way of actual ticket booking/marking system.